# WP7 Silverlight Bing Map - MapPolyline doesn't zoom or move with map

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, dictionary, bing-maps

I added a MapPolyline to a Map control as follows:

```
<Map>
  <MapLayer>
    <MapItemsControl>
      <MapPolyline Locations="{Binding locations}"/>
...
```

This looks fine initially.  However, if I pan or zoom the map the MapPolyline doesn't move accordingly - it stays in the same place.  Is there something extra that needs to be done to link the MapPolyline to the current map location/zoom level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put it directly to the MapLayer. I don't know what a MapItemsControl does, when it is inside a MapLayer (I used it directly inside a Map before), but this contains non-zooming elements.